# how to display the uploaded file contents as object using file reader in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am using the file upload function to upload a json file and read it contents here the issue is the result i am getting is in string format not in object how can i display it in the object

below is my code :

**.html**

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" (change)="filechanged($event)" />
   </div>
```

**.ts**

```
filechanged(e){
       this.file = e.target.files[0];
       this.uploadDocument(this.file);
      }

 uploadDocument(file){
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload =(e) => {
      this.Name =  fileReader.result;
      console.log(typeof this.Name);
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
  }
```

here i am getting the out put type as string not as object

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string using `JSON.parse(<your_data>)`

```
  uploadDocument(file){
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload =(e) => {
      this.Name =  JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
      console.log(typeof this.Name);
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
  }
```

[Click here to try the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fuura?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).